# Passing xml to angular from web api controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an api controller which generates response as xml and need to pass this xml to an external angularjs application and parse this to show result. 
I have tried this so far.

```
/PaymentSuccess.html?response=<xml>....<xml>
```

I dont think this is the best way of doing because the uri seems lengthy and ugly.

Is there any better way so that i can pass the xml to the uri and read that from the angular application.

Comment: Why pass the XML to the AngularJS app? Why not just call the API directly from the AngularJS app?

Comment: Angular controller not requesting this service, I just need to send an information to angular page.